# Consistent way of calculating average tree size using repeated cross validation?

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation, cart, rpart

I'd like to examine the behaviour of my classifier concerning the tree size. That is, I'm using rpart to build and prune the tree. For the rest of my analysis I'm running repeated 10 Fold Cross validation. I thought, it might be interesting to check stability/behaviour of the tree size picked by rpart. However, I'm struggling a little bit with the implementation. I thought about computing the average tree size over my 10 Fols CV and then check whether this average changes by repeating the process several times. However, the average is obviously not guaranteed to be an integer, which looks not so nice. Is this still a good way to handle it? I appreciate any comments and inputs! Thank you!